# Вирус на сайте. index.php все время обновляется

Tags: php, nginx, yii

Сайт подхватил вирус, который изменяет index.php и создает еще несколько файлов. При попытке их удалить, в том числе и index.php они сразу же создаются заново. Как определить, что создает эти файлы постоянно?

Comment: Надо обратиться к администратору хостинга

Comment: А администратору хостинга что делать?

Comment: Администратору хостинга (не сайта, а хостинга) надо бы знать, что делать в таких случаях. Антивирус какой-нибудь запустить, например...

Comment: Пусть смотрит `ls -lah` и дату обновления `index.php` + если используете git, то чекнет дату последнего pull-a и доступы по ssh. Это даст ему уверенность, что не вы над ним шутите. Далее, можно попробовать сменить владельца на директорию и рутовый пароль, если не поможет, то можно установить права только на чтение директории и оставить там один единственный ваш index.php, а далее, в более спокойном режиме решать вопрос.

Comment: Примерно так и сделали, index.php не перезаписывается, но другие файлы появляются сразу же после удаления и сам прежний index файл появляется, но с другим расширением. Дальше что делать непонятно